# Is it possible to use both VPC peering and Transit Gateway?

Tags: vpc-peering, aws-vpc

I currently have 2 VPCs with an InternetGateway each VPC1 and VPC2.

- I need VPC2 to use VPC1's public IP.
- I'd rather modify VPC1 as little as possible.
- There is a lot of traffic between these 2 VPCs.

I know I can setup a TransitGateway between these 2 VPCs and have VPC2 use the VPC1's IGW.

Would it be possible to have the "non-internet" traffic still going through VPC peering to reduce cost?

What I'm not sure about is the route back from VPC1 to VPC2 that would need to be the same for peering and TransitGateway.

Is there any way to achieve this? Is there any other alternative?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can continue to use VPC peering for non-Internet-bound traffic between VPC1 and VPC2. VPC peering allows private communication between VPCs, and it doesn't incur data transfer costs. This setup allows you to minimize costs for traffic that doesn't need to go over the Internet.